# How to get the objects from an array in angular or javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of object, I want to get the objects from 'Seconditem' in my array. I have tried using object.keys but its not working. Code is below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmfjux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  ngOnInit() {
    const sampleArray = [
      {
        mainitem: "My item 1",
        Seconditem: {
          createddate: "30-01-02",
          enddate: "30-01-03"
        }
      }
    ];
    // console.log(sampleArray)
    Object.keys(sampleArray.Seconditem).forEach(key => {
      console.log(key);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `sampleArray` is an array, so if you want to access the first item of that array you'd need to do `sampleArray[0]`

Comment: `sampleArray.map((val) => { console.log( val.Seconditem.createddate) })`. use `map()` and get your values.

Comment: I am sorry Najam but you are using `map` in the wrong way, that is a functional operator used to obtain a modified version of an array, not to get its values, for get them you should just use `forEach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, your sampleArray is an array and not an object so you first need to specify an index, you just need to add [0] as in:

```
const item = {};

Object.keys(sampleArray[0].Seconditem).forEach(key => {
  item[key] = sampleArray[0].Seconditem[key];
});

console.log({ item });
```

(anyway I am not sure why that needs to be array, maybe you should just convert it to a normal object, or if it's an array because you will also have to add other objects like the one already there then instead of `[0]` you will need a `[idx]` where `idx` is an index you loop through)

Comment: I need whole object not only key actually like this in console  createddate: "30-01-02",
          enddate: "30-01-03"

Comment: no problem, I edited my answer to print in the console exactly that :)

Comment: I mean I need all values inside object like this {
          createddate: "30-01-02",
          enddate: "30-01-03"
        }

Comment: ok I added that as well to my answer, you need some object where to save those values in my case I called it `item`. I hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

you can not do sampleArray.secondItem as sampleArray is an array not an object

you have to iterate over array to get the keys of every object in the array

```
    sampleArray.forEach(x => {
      Object.keys(x.Seconditem).forEach(key => {
        console.log(key, ': ', x.SecondItem[key]);
      });
    });
```

i have update this link to print the object values
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cckvqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for answer ,I need whole object not only key actually like this in console createddate: "30-01-02", enddate: "30-01-03"

Comment: check out the link i have also updated the answer it will print both key and value